# How many integers from $1 \to 10^{10}$ are not perfect squares, cubes, or fifth powers?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

How can I solve this question, using the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion?

Count the number of integers in the range 1 to $10^{10}$ are not perfect squares, cubes, or fifth powers. That is, the integer cannot be written in the form $m^r$ where $m$ is an integer and $r$ is one of $2,3,5$.

Comment: Do you mean $10^{10}$ or 1010? (and also, please show something that you've tried to do, and any of your approaches)

Answer (score 1):

Compute the number of squares, cubes, and fifth powers.  Now note that you have counted the sixth, tenth, and fifteenth powers twice each, so subtract them.  You have counted the thirtieth powers three times and subtracted them three times, so add them once more.

Comment: That's what I tried to do:
So the number of squares is sqrt(10^10)
 number of square cubes sqrt_cubes(10^10)
 number of square fifth sqrt_fifth(10^10)
Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$n = 10^{10} - \left( \lfloor \sqrt{10^{10}} \rfloor + \lfloor \sqrt[3]{10^{10}} \rfloor + \lfloor \sqrt[6]{10^{10}} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt[6]{10^{10}} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt[15]{10^{10}} \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt[10]{10^{10}} \rfloor + \lfloor \sqrt[30]{10^{10}} \rfloor \right) = 9,999,897,804$$